# Pagination - works on local but not live dev!

Tags: loop, pagination

Can anyone please shed some light as to why the following to print out page numbers works on my local dev server but not on my live server?

Both server are running same version of PHP.

My Loop

```
<?php
global $paged;
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
//do stuff
endwhile; ?>
```

My Pagination

```
<?php echo '
<div id="pagination">
<a class="first page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link(1).'">[First]</a>';
for($i=1;$i<=$query->max_num_pages;$i++)
echo '<a class="page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'">'.$i.'</a>';
echo '<a class="last page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link($query->max_num_pages).'">[Last]</a></div>
';
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

The issue clearly lies within:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$query->max_num_pages;$i++)
```

The first & last print out fine - the page numbers do not.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

If i do this it works:

```
for($i=1;$i<=99;$i++)
```

So the issue is with:

```
$query->max_num_pages;
```

Any more thoughts?

Comment: Well, I just copied the code and it works (unfortunately? ;)) just fine for my demo website.

Comment: Haha, thanks for that, hence why i'm banging my head off the desk with this right now.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all plugins? Does `WPDEBUG` output anything?

Comment: Didn't help, but thanks for the suggestion @user2019515 - I'm syncing my local version with live dev via git so the installs are identical, i'm baffled!

Comment: Dev and live both using linux/windows?

Comment: @vancoder - thanks for the reply, they are both Linux, both using same PHP & Apache version.

Comment: `get_pagenum_link` looks like it consults permalink settings. have you updated your permalinks on live?

Comment: I think your second code sample has `endif` when it should have `endfor`. I'm sure it's just a typo, but best to be clear.

Comment: You didn't say if `WP_DEBUG` outputs anything? Also, try a `var_dump($query)` on both versions, and compare results.

Comment: The endif is part of the loop. Tried all the debugging you can imaging including your suggestions, nothing, nish, nada :-(

Comment: Hm, nope, the `endif` isn't part of the loop in the code you entered here - unless you mean the `if` before the `endwhile`, which is very confusing. Anyway, your `var_dump` has more than 2 pages in it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
//global $wp_rewrite;
$loop->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $loop->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

$pagination = array(
    'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => $loop->max_num_pages,

    'current' => 0,
    'show_all' => true,
    'prev_next'    => true,
    'prev_text'    => __('&laquo; Back'),
    'next_text'    => __('Newxt&raquo;'),
    'type' => 'plain'
    );

if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
    $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged    ' );    

    echo "<div class=\"pagination\" >";    
echo paginate_links( $pagination );    
echo "</div>";    
?>
```

Comment: How does this help? Please explain.